# How to POST method calling from service Angular 12 to the REST using web api in asp.net mvc

Tags: json, angular, api, model-view-controller

I would like to know how to how to POST method calling from service Angular 10 to the REST using web api in asp.net mvc. I have attached my code I tired. This is Angular 6. I need to know how to convert to the angular 10?

```
PostUser(usr: User){
  var body = JSON.stringify(usr);
  var headerOptions = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' });
  var requestOption = new HttpResponse({ method : RequstMethod.Post, headers: headerOptions });
  return this.http.post('https://localhost:44339/api/Users', body, requestOption).map(x=> x.json());
```

Comment: do you have any error ? if yes, share it please

Comment: Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object' in  map(x=> x.json()); and 'Argument of type '{ method: any; headers: HttpHeaders; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ body?: unknown; headers?: HttpHeaders; status?: number; statusText?: string; url?: string; }'.

Comment: data is automatically in JSON, you don"t need to call json() method